# Java Swing Call Method Before Focus Change

Tags: java, swing

I am working with a **java swing form** that contains a `JTextField`. The text field needs input validation , validation is performed when the field losses focus . i.e clicking anyware apart from the field itself.

The form also contains a `JButton` to clear(cancel) the form . Now whenever I press the cancel button and the `Textfield` is the currently focused component the validation function is invoked. This should not happen.

I have tried `InputVerifier` and `Focuslistener`

Is there a way I can know what component caused the focus to change ?

Comment: To help us help you, please consider creating and posting your [mcve] (please see the link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FocusListener` to react to a `focusLost` event. There you can retrieve the destination of the focus via `getOppositeComponent()` from the `FocusEvent`. If the destination is the clear/cancel/whatever button do nothing, otherwise validate.

A very basic example for this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        Component comp = e.getOppositeComponent();
        if (comp instanceof JButton) {
            JButton button = (JButton) comp;
            String buttonText = button.getText();
            if (buttonText.equals("Cancel")) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // do the validation
        System.out.println("validate");
    }

});
```

---

Actually camickr's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617775/5337924) is a lot simpler than mine above. I had no idea that there was built in solution for this.

Comment: I needed something to work with the FocusAdapter . camickr's solution only works for InputVerifier as mentioned .

Answer (score 4):

> This is fine but the form contains a JButton to clear(cancel) the form

You can use:

```
clearButton.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);
```

to prevent the `InputVerifier` from being invoked when you click on the button.

Comment: This is **THE** answer to the OP's question.